# Filtering MongoDB query with Swift & Realm

Tags: swift, mongodb, realm

I am trying to run an Atlas query via Realm using swift, code is as follows:

```
     app.login(credentials: Credentials.anonymous) { results in

            switch results {
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Login failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            case .success(let user):
                print("Successfully logged in as user \(user)")

                let client = self.app.currentUser!.mongoClient("mongodb-atlas")
                let database = client.database(named: "Incidents")
                let collection = database.collection(withName: "Incidents")

                let qf: Document = ["incidentDetails.lastUpdated":"{$gt:ISODate('2022-07-23')}"]

                collection.find(filter: qf) { result in
                    switch result {
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print("Login failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")

                    case .success(let documents):
                        print("Great Success")
                        for doc in documents {
                            print("Title: \(doc)")
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

This executes successfully, logs an anon. user in runs the query returning success, however I get no documents back. I assume at this point it is because of my filter document

```
let qf: Document = ["incidentDetails.lastUpdated":"{$gt:ISODate('2022-07-23')}"]
```

But I am at a loss as to how to write this in Swift. Essentially, I only want to return documents updated within the last few days. I can run this via Atlas using

{"incidentDetails.lastUpdated": { $gt:ISODate('2022-07-23')}}

Using other fields in the objects work, such as:

```
let qf: Document = [“incidentDetails.incidentType”:“Small”]
```

Then it returns 20 documents as expected.

I've tried nesting documents:

```
let qf: Document = ["incidentDetails.lastUpdated": ["$gt":"ISODate('2022-07-23')"]]
```

The incidentDetails.lastUpdated field in the document is in Date format, and I've tried using ISODate and just Date.  The queries that I run via Realm work fine in Atlas if I take the code from the app log in Realm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours of trying, I found the answer.  It seems that via Realm / MongoDB driver (at least with Switch) the Date data type is treated as a number, so changing to this resolves:

```
let maxDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: -3 * 24 * 3600)
let qf: Document = ["incidentDetails.lastUpdated":["$gt": .datetime(maxDate)]]
```